# MUI : How to efficiently migrate from Desktop website to Mobile

Tags: reactjs, mobile, material-ui

I wrongly started developing a React-MUI application only for desktop. Now I wanna make it responsible on mobile too and I would like some suggestion on the best approach to render components.

While migrating the TopHeaderMenu, I have already tried the approach of having two Boxes: one which is display for mobile and one for desktop :

```
 <Box display={{ xs: 'none', lg: 'block' }}>
      <Menu />
    </Box>
    <Box display={{ xs: 'block', lg: 'none' }}>
      <AppMenu />
    </Box>
```

With a nice result :
[image: Desktop]
[image: Mobile]

As you can see there are not too many pages accessible by the user, so my next approach would be to re-acreate each component also for Mobile, and use the same approach above.

For example I am at the Route : `http://localhost:3000/user/submit-request`

which render a Form component :

```
const SubmitRequestPageUser = (props) => {

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
      <Box display={{ xs: 'none', lg: 'block' }}>
        <FormSubmission />
      </Box>
      <Box display={{ xs: 'block', lg: 'none' }}>
        <MobileFormSubmission />
      </Box> 
   </Paper>
  )
}
```

Will I encounter any performance issues by not displaying Component this way, or this is a good approach to developing with MUI ? And if it is not could you suggest me any resources or tutorial which demostrate a good approach to it

Kind Regards

Giovanni

Answer (score 0):

The main approach of responsive is using one component for ALL screen sizes. You can use media queries to detect if needed.
In most cases, you will never have any performance issue cause by Material-UI.
You can use [Hidden Componenent here](https://material-ui.com/components/hidden/) but in rare cases in my experience.
Official document about media queries here also: https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/